# I am unable to find open vpn packages in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: openvpn

I am installing openvpn but it displays that **unable to locate vpn package**

Then i had done checking mounting in /mnt/isolinux.  But cant find any entry of open vpn package.  Please help me

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer?

Answer (score 1):

## Search packages from command line using apt

Searching for all packages containing the string 'openvpn'

```
apt search openvpn
```

## Check package informations for a specific package-name

You can see version & source informations for a specific package (here: openvpn) as follows:

```
apt-cache policy openvpn
```

This results in my 16.04 installation in the following output:

> openvpn:
>   Installed: (none)
>   Candidate: 2.3.10-1ubuntu2
>   Version table:
>        2.3.10-1ubuntu2 500
>           500 http://de2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages

As you can see, i haven't it installed yet, but i can install 2.3.10 via the default repositories configured on my system.

## Installing package by package-name using apt

You can install the package `openvpn` as follows

```
sudo apt install openvpn
```